# Conditionally initialize class variable depending on the template type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Suppose I have the following code:

```cpp
enum class Type
{
    Type32,
    Type64
};

template<Type T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    using MyType = typename std::conditional<T == Type::Type32, uint32_t, uint64_t>::type;
    
    MyType getSum()
    {
        MyType sum = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0;i < sizeof(arr);i ++)
        {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

 private:
     //MyType arr[4] = { 0x1234, 0x5678, 0x9ABC, 0xDEF0 }; // for Type::Type32
     //MyType arr[2] = { 0x12345678, 0x9ABCDE }; // for Type::Type64
};
```

I try to initialize a class variable depends on the template type with the same name but different type and value. How can I do that? I probably looking for a solution that works in c++11.

Comment: The simplest solution is to inherit `arr` from another template, and then specialize it. Are you familiar with specialized templates, how they work, and how to use them?

Comment: Unfortunately, template specialization is an advanced topic that cannot be fully explained in just one or two sentences. If someone's "not really familiar with templates", doesn't it make sense to invest some time, first, in learning C++ template fundamentals, like this one? C++ is just too complicated, it's not practical to learn it by asking one question at a time on Stackoverflow. Which C++ textbook are you using, to learn C++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple way:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Type { Type32, Type64 };

template <Type>
struct As128Bits;

template <>
struct As128Bits<Type::Type32> {
    using Integer = std::uint32_t;

    std::array<Integer, 4> data{0x1234, 0x5678, 0x9ABC, 0xDEF0};
};

template <>
struct As128Bits<Type::Type64> {
    using Integer = std::uint64_t;

    std::array<Integer, 2> data{0x12345678, 0x9ABCDE};
};

template <Type T>
struct MyClass : private As128Bits<T> {
    using Integer = typename As128Bits<T>::Integer;
    using As128Bits<T>::data;

    Integer getSum() {
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (auto const val : data) {
            sum += val;
        }
        return sum;
    }
};
```

Comment: for me, this is a nice solution. I was close to a similar one, but missed few details and that's why it didn't work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use tag dispatch (with a delegating constructor):

```cpp
template<Type T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    using MyType = typename std::conditional<T == Type::Type32, uint32_t, uint64_t>::type;

    // This will call one of the constructors below
    MyClass() : MyClass(std::integral_constant<Type, T>{}) {}

    MyType getSum() { /* ... */ }

 private:

    explicit MyClass(std::integral_constant<Type, Type::Type32>) : arr{ 0x1234, 0x5678, 0x9ABC, 0xDEF0 } {}
    explicit MyClass(std::integral_constant<Type, Type::Type64>) : arr{ 0x12345678, 0x9ABCDEF0 } {}

    MyType arr[T == Type::Type32 ? 4 : 2];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you can move different part into separate class and do specialization. (or you can do full class specialization if it fits)

```cpp
template <Type T>
struct MyData;

template <>
struct MyData<Type::Type32>{
    uint32_t arr[4] = { 0x1234, 0x5678, 0x9ABC, 0xDEF0 };
};

template <>
struct MyData<Type::Type64>{
    uint64_t arr[2] = { 0x12345678, 0x9ABCDE };
};

template<Type T>
class MyClass: private MyData<T>{
    // common functions
};
```

Comment: Beat you by 5 seconds ;-)

Comment: I think I'm a little earlier?

Comment: @appleapple: Yep, you won by 5 seconds according to the post timestamps.

Comment: Ah damn, you are 5 seconds earlier. Well, have an upvote then